# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Error while updating GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview, auto-update

I am updating a GridView. If i click on UPDATE then the grid is updating in the database, but i m getting error on webpage.

ERROR
**"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"**

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the entries are getting updated in the database. because a gridview does not need any datatype specification to display the data given to it.

so please check again